# Upload file to cloud storage using presigned url - make put request

Tags: flutter

I read file/image using ImagePicker

```
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

```
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> uploadImageToStorage(XFile imageFile, String presignedUrl) async {
    var stream = http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'image/png'};
    var uri = Uri.parse(presignedUrl);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("PUT", uri);
    var multipartFileSign = http.MultipartFile('profile_pic', stream, length, filename: basename(imageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFileSign);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    var response = await request.send();
    return response;
  }
```

I get error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 941:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 638:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1589:7                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37268:58                              <fn>
```

I verified that the presignedUrl works by uploading a file to cloud storage using that url through python:

```
def check_put_url(url):
    file = 'sample_files/p1.jpg
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        put_resp = requests.put(url, data=f, timeout=20)
```

Comment: That's a CORS error. (Confirm by checking in the Developer Tools > Network tab of the browser.) Check with the server vendor how to emit to correct CORS headers.